# Improve performance of calculating sum of word-scores on large vector of strings?

Tags: r, string, performance, loops, vectorization

I have a character strings that looks like this :

```
 [1] "What can we learn from the Mahabharata "                                                                
 [2] "What are the most iconic songs associated with the Vietnam War "                                        
 [3] "What are some major social faux pas to avoid when visiting Malta "                                      
 [4] "Will Ready Boost technology contribute to CFD software usage "                                          
 [5] "Who is Jon Snow " ...
```

and a data frame that assigns each word a score :

```
   word score
   the    11
    to     9
  What     9
     I     7
     a     6
   are     6
```

I want to assign each one of my strings the sum of the scores of the words contained in it, my solution is the following function

```
 score_fun<- function(x)

 # obtaining the list of words 

 {z <- unlist(strsplit(x,' ')); 

 # returning the sum of the words' scores     

 return(sum(word_scores$score[word_scores$word %in% z]))} 

 # using sapply() in conjunction with the function  

 scores <- sapply(my_strings, score_fun, USE.NAMES = F)

 # the output will look like 
 scores
 [1] 20 26 24  9  0  0 38 32 30  0
```

the issue I'm having is one of performance, I have about 500k of strings, and over a million words, using the function takes more than one hour on my I-7, 16GB machine.
in addition, the solution just feels inelegant, clunky..

is there a better (more efficient) solution?

to reproduce the data:

```
 my_strings <- c("What can we learn from the Mahabharata ", "What are the most iconic songs associated with the Vietnam War ", 
"What are some major social faux pas to avoid when visiting Malta ", 
"Will Ready Boost technology contribute to CFD software usage ", 
"Who is Jon Snow ", "Do weighing scales measure mass or weight ", 
"What will happen to the money in foreign banks after demonetizing 500 and 1000 rupee notes ", 
"Is it mandatory to stay for 11 months in a rented house if the rental agreement was made for 11 months ", 
"What are some really good positive comments to say on a cricket field to your teammates ", 
"Is Donald Trump fact free ")


word_scores <- data.frame(word = c("the", "to", "What", "I", "a", "are", "in", "of", "and", "do"
), score = c(11L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: When you say *"I have a million words"*, how many unique words with non-zero scores are in your lookup table? Also, it looks like you're trying to manually implement a word-vectorizer, these already exist (in R, Python, word2vec etc.), have a look. You might be able to store your input sentences in word-vector form; the word-order doesn't matter, and I imagine you don't care about counts? (multiple occurrences?)

Comment: Look for e.g. *"Vector Representations of Words"*. There's a ton of existing work and packages in that.

Comment: If you want to get actual performance comparison numbers, please add code reading in one specific [large standard online corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_corpora), and your example lookup table(/dictionary) of word-scores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tokenize to words with `tidytext::unnest_tokens` and then join and aggregate:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data_frame(string = my_strings, id = seq_along(string)) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, string, 'words', to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
    distinct() %>%
    left_join(word_scores) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(score = sum(score, na.rm = TRUE))

#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>       id score
#>    <int> <int>
#> 1      1    20
#> 2      2    26
#> 3      3    24
#> 4      4     9
#> 5      5     0
#> 6      6     0
#> 7      7    38
#> 8      8    32
#> 9      9    30
#> 10    10     0
```

Keep the original strings if you like, or just re-join them by ID at the end.

On small data it's much slower, but it gets quicker at scale, e.g. when `my_strings` is resampled to length 10,000:

```r
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   Reduce 5440.03300 5656.41350 5815.2094 5814.0406 5944.9969 6206.2502   100
   sapply  460.75930  486.94336  511.2762  503.4932  532.2363  746.8376   100
 tidytext   86.92182   94.65745  101.7064  100.1487  107.3289  134.7276   100
```

Comment: I like the solution, by the step `left_join(word_scores) %>% ` keeps crashing my Rstudio for some reason, even when done in isolation :(

Comment: R, or RStudio? There are a lot of reason R can bomb out, but maybe try updating to [the devel version of dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/) and the brand-new R 3.4.0 just in case it's a bug that's already been patched.

Comment: I think I found the issue,  the join was between a character and a factor (normally not a big deal). I fixed the issue, now it works, and it's super fast , I couldn't get the exact time becuase Sys.time() didn't work for some reason. thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a dataframe of the split words and then merge to *word_scores* and finally aggregates scores by phrase id. This approach avoids the iterative `sapply` loop calculation.

```
list_strings <- lapply(my_strings, function(i) unique(unlist(strsplit(s, split=" "))))      

ids <- lapply(seq(length(list_strings)), function(i) rep(i, length(list_strings[[i]])))

phrases_df <- data.frame(id=Reduce(append, ids), word=Reduce(append, list_strings))      
aggdf <- aggregate(score~id, merge(phrases_df, word_scores, by="word"), FUN=sum)

aggdf 
#   id score
# 1  1    20
# 2  2    26
# 3  3    24
# 4  4     9
# 5  7    38
# 6  8    32
# 7  9    30
```

---

While a `microbenchmark` shows this approach is slower (1 milliseconds = 1,000 microseconds) with posted data, it may scale better with larger amount of data than the `sapply`.

```
library(micorbenchmark)

microbenchmark({
   list_strings <- lapply(my_strings, function(i) unique(unlist(strsplit(s, split=" "))))

   ids <- lapply(seq(length(list_strings)), function(i) rep(i, length(list_strings[[i]])))

   phrases_df <- data.frame(id=Reduce(append, ids), word=Reduce(append, list_strings))      
   aggdf <- aggregate(score~id, merge(phrases_df, word_scores, by="word"), FUN=sum)

})

# Unit: milliseconds
#      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 5.623328 5.808831 6.177336 5.964018 6.252019 10.09706   100

microbenchmark({
  score_fun<- function(x) {
     z <- unlist(strsplit(x,' '))
     return(sum(word_scores$score[word_scores$word %in% z]))
  } 
  scores <- sapply(my_strings, score_fun, USE.NAMES = F)
})

# Unit: microseconds
#       min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
# 809.382 843.307 1005.366 865.442 1209.983 1873.32   100
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it doesn't appear to address my need(unless I am missing something), the aggregate score is supposed to be assigned to each string, the output of the first command of your answer `list_strings <- Reduce(append,
                    lapply(my_strings, function(s) unique(unlist(strsplit(s, split=" ")))))` is one long character vector , not grouped by each specific string.